# jstree drag and drop order reversed

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jstree

When I selected multiple nodes and drag to change the order, the result order of selected is reversed, is there anyway to prevent this from happening ?

For example:

- Node 1
- Node 2
- Node 3
- Node 4
- Node 5
- Node 6

If I select Node 2 and Node 3, drag and drop them in between node 4 and node 5, i get the following result

- Node 1
- Node 4
- Node 3
- Node 2
- Node 5
- Node 6

I wanna get the following result instead

- Node 1
- Node 4
- Node 2
- Node 3
- Node 5
- Node 6

  $("#tree_4").jstree({
          "plugins": ["wholerow", "dnd", "state", "types", "search", "cookies"],
          "core": {
              "themes": {
                  "responsive": true
              },
              "check_callback": true,
              "data": {
                  "url": function(node) {
                      return "/dashboard/admin/mpcats/categoriestrees";
                  },
                  "data": function(node) {
                       return {
                           "parent": node.id
                       };
                  }
              }
          },
      })

Comment: Can you post some code?